# ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone point me to an article that shows the dropdownlist being populated from linq to sql (text and value being set).

Thanks
Danny

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now that the HtmlHelper extension takes an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, I don't create SelectList's, but usually just create the SelectListItems with LINQ.

**Controller**

```
ViewData["CategoryID"] = categories.Select( c => new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Text = c.CategoryName,
                                                     Value = c.CategoryID
                                                 }
                                          );
```

**View**

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("CategoryID") %>
```

or if I want a default selection

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("CategoryID",
                      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryID"],
                      "Select a Category" ) %>
```

**EDIT**:

The interesting bit about the dropdown list is that you need to supply a range of values from which to select a single value that fits into your actual data model.  I typically provide the range (menu items) via view data and expect back the model values when the page is posted.  If you wanted strongly-typed menus as well, you'd need to provide a view-only model that encapulates your real model and any menus.  This would involve, on posting, the use of prefixes to identify the model elements.  The trade-off, to my mind, is simpler model binding on post vs. the use of strongly-typed menus in the view.  I'm not hung up on the latter, so I opt not to put my menus in the model.  If you wanted to do this, though, it might look like the following.

**Model**

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryMenu { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Controller**

*Display action*

```
var model = new CategoryViewModel();
model.CategoryMenu = categories.Select( c => new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Text = c.CategoryName,
                                                     Value = c.CategoryID
                                                 }
                                      );

...
return View(model);
```

*Create action*

```
[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Prefix="Category")]Category category )
{
   ...
}
```

**View**

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Category.Name") %>

<%= Html.DropDownList("Category.CategoryID",
                      Model.CategoryMenu,
                      "Select a Category" ) %>
```

Comment: Thats great. Could you provide an example using this with the ViewModel pattern. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's one great article by [Rob Connery](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-and-html-attributes/)

**Controller Code**

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var categories = from c in db.Categories select c;
ViewData["CategoryID"] = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
```

**View Markup**

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("CategoryID")%>
```

Comment: You don't need the second argument in the html helper. The method will look that up for you if you just pass the "CategoryID".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add html attributes to your  tags this would be a way of doing it.
Pass a Model to your View e.i. "return View(someModel)" then in the View:

```
        <select id="Groups" name="Groups">
            <% foreach (SelectListItem item in Model.GroupsDropDown)
               {
                   if (item.Selected)
                   {%>
                        <option selected="selected" title="<%= item.Text %>">
                            <%= item.Text%></option>
                    <%}
                     else
                    {%>
                        <option title="<%= item.Text %>">
                            <%= item.Text%></option>
                    <%} %>
            <% } %>
        </select>
```

GroupsDropDown is a property in your Model like this:

public IEnumerable GroupsDropDown { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Write in the view:

```
@{
TaskManagerContext context = new TaskManagerContext();

IEnumerable<TestTask1.Models.User> CDrop = context.Users.ToList();
List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var c in CDrop)
{
    SelectListItem i = new SelectListItem();
    i.Text = c.Username.ToString();
    i.Value = c.ID.ToString();
    selectList.Add(i);
}
```

}

You can reference it ike that:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserID,
                          new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text"));
```

You can also choose a specific row:

```
TaskManagerContext context = new TaskManagerContext();
UsersRepository repo = new UsersRepository();
User user = repo.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == ViewBag.UserId);
ViewBag.User = user;

<div><h3><label>@ViewBag.Title1</label>@ViewBag.User.Username</h3></div>
```